# Chicken considered as kosher animal?

Tags: halacha, kashrut-kosher, poultry

Why isn't chicken considered pareve? Fowl is not an animal that gives milk to its outsprings so why is chicken in the category of kosher animal?

Comment: See: https://www.myjewishlearning.com/article/ask-the-expert-pareve-poultry/